# Mongoose populate not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am very much new in using mongoose and had done simple db work on mongodb.

Seeing my usecase I found this method of doing it in mongodb using mongoose. However I am not getting expected result as shown in tutorials.

My Schemas

```
var EventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    root: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'root'},
    voting: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Voting'}]
});

var VotingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    events: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Events'},
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

var Events = mongoose.model('Events', EventsSchema, 'event');
var Voting = mongoose.model('Voting', VotingSchema, 'voting');
```

I have these two schemas initially. I want to create a voting event. When voting event is created then in `voting schema` events id should be stored as suggested and more I want is that voting event reference should be stored in `EventSchema`.

```
var events = new Events({});
events.save()
.then((events) => {
    var voting = new Voting({ events: events._id, title: "Test Title" });
    voting.save()
    .then((voting) => {
        Voting.findOne({title: 'Test Title'})
        .populate('events')
        .exec(function(err, voting){
            console.log(voting, err);
            if(err) res.sendStatus(401).send();
            else res.sendStatus(200).send();
        })

    })
    .catch((e) => {
        res.sendStatus(401).send();
    });
})
.catch((e) => {
    res.sendStatus(401).send();
})
```

What I am getting on console is

```
{ 
    _id: 5b83eca82a3cfb1dec21ddc9,
    events: { voting: [], _id: 5b83eca82a3cfb1dec21ddc8, __v: 0 },
    title: 'Test Title',
    __v: 0 
}
```

My MongoDB looks like this

voting

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b83eca82a3cfb1dec21ddc9"),
    "events" : ObjectId("5b83eca82a3cfb1dec21ddc8"),
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

events

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b83eca82a3cfb1dec21ddc8"),
    "voting" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I am not sure how will my mongodb look like. But after attempting the code once it looks like above.

I must be doing something wrong or missing something important. But this kind of code is there in docs too. [docs link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Help me in sorting this issue.

Thanks

Comment: please read in detail https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html . It contain method how to add subdocument

Comment: @deepakthomas thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Array of ObjIds should be defined this way in schema:

```
var EventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    root: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'root'},
    voting: {type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Voting'}//**array bracers** 
});
```

Also calling  population over a field of type array like root field will return an empty array in the res of the API, see query hit by `mongoose.set('debug', true);` you will notice that mongoose is searching in event model not root.

though you have to tell mongoose in the population method which model to use in order to get the population working, unless you tell mongoose which model to search in .

```
populate({path:'vooting',model:'vooting'})
```

Comment: can you explain bit more of 2nd part of answer?

Comment: If you have defined array of objectid In the parent schema as we defined, you should provide populate an extra details in 5he populate method by specifiying the path which is the field to populate and the model that the field refers to

Comment: i tested it now. results are same.

Comment: No the path should be the field name and the model should be the event